# How to get the request's Authentication Header in Tornado

Tags: python, jwt, tornado

I've been looking on how to get the Authorization Header from a Tornado GET/POST Request, but there's none. Anyone can help on this?

The reason is that I want to implement **JWT** in my Python application.

For example, this tornado API just creates a GET request:

```
class HeaderHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        headers = tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders()
        response = {
            'message': str(headers)
        }
        self.write(response)
```

I want to access this API via [http://localhost:{port}](http://localhost) and I will add a header which is

```
Authentication: Bearer {token}
```

But this code doesn't work. It cannot fetch the **authorization header** passed to the request. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Tornado, accessing the bearer token from JWT can be achieved by:

```
token = self.request.headers.get('Authorization')
```

Comment: I forgot to mark a correct answer. I consider both answers as correct but this is more concise to me. So here, a check mark.

Comment: `token = self.request.headers['Authorization']` also works for me

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs, a [request object](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest) containing headers is available as [`RequestHandler.request`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.request), so try e.g.

```
self.write(repr(self.request.headers))
```